# jquery LOAD content simultaneously into different DIV

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, jquery

I have this code :

```
$("#box1").load(""+ siteAddress +"page/internal-url-1/");
  $("#box2").load(""+ siteAddress +"page/internal-url-2/");

  var refreshId = setInterval(function(){
     $("#box1").load(""+ siteAddress +"page/internal-url-1/");
     $('#box2').load(""+ siteAddress +"page/internal-url-2/");

  }, 10000);
```

i only get load result form "internal-url-1", the "#box2" keep empty, it doesn't load the content.Any body know how to fixed this ??

Thank you guys...

Comment: why u using `var refresh ID` ? no need to write same code twice, later  one is perfect

Answer (score 0):

its seem that code is ok, but may be the timer problem
because     1000 ms = 1 second  so 10000 ms = 10 second and the time to load the page is greator than 10 seconds so that is why the box2 is not loaded. its just an assumption